# Missing some datas while passing data from child component to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have function in parent component

```
const getFilename=  (filedata)=>  
{
    console.log(filedata);      
}
```

And pass call a child component from parent

```
<FileUpload getFieDetails={getFilename} />
```

Childcomponent function:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

const uploadHandler = (event) => {     
    const file = event.target.files[0];      
    console.log(file);     
    if(!file) return;      
      
    file.isUploading = true;
    setFiles((prevState) => [...prevState, file]) 
    props.getFieDetails(files);
)
}
```

when i console **files** from child component all the value is listing.But in parent component one data is always missing.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setFiles` is asynchronous. When you call `setFiles(...)`, React re-renders your component and the `files` state will be stale until the next render. Therefore, calling `props.getFileDetails(files)` immediately after will pass the previous `files` state.

#### Option 1:

Create a new array and call `setFiles` and `props.getFilename` with the new value.

```js
const uploadHandler = () => {
  ...
  const newFiles = [...files, file];
  setFiles(newFiles);
  props.getFileDetails(newFiles);
};
```

#### Option 2:

Call `props.getFileDetails` in a `useEffect`.

```js
const uploadHandler = () => {
  ...
  const newFiles = [...files, file];
  setFiles(newFiles);
  props.getFileDetails(newFiles);
};

useEffect(() => {
  props.getFileDetails(files);
}, [props.getFileDetails, files]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getFieDetails` inside setFiles callback

like this:

```
const uploadHandler = event => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(file);
  if (!file) return;
  file.isUploading = true;

  setFiles(prevState => {
    let filesArr = [...prevState, file];
    props.getFieDetails(filesArr)
    return filesArr
  });
};
```